# I'm doing this like I normally do, but why isn't the binding working?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is something very simple and I was sure I knew how to do this but it's not working. In my VM I have this simple property:

```
private string _textBoxText;
public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return _textBoxText; }
    set
    {
        _textBoxText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxText");
    }
}
```

Next I tried to create a simple two-way bind between a TextBox and that property like so:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Grid.Column="2"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         MinWidth="300"
         Margin="10 10 10 0"
         Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I thought that was all I needed to do but I set a breakpoint inside the above property setter to see what's happening but when I type into the textbox the breakpoint is never reached, the property is never set by the text in the textbox.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I should mention I have my VM set as the datacontext, I have other bindings that work so it's not related to the datacontext. Also INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented properly since it works for other bindings.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio? As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the Binding of a TextBox's Text property is redundant. You may however want to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to update the source property immediately when you type into the TextBox.

Comment: Sounds like a missing `DataContext` to me, can you post the full XAML and class behind it.

Comment: Clemens thank you, I needed to use the UpdateSourceTrigger property!